# Removing a Fragment from the back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a 3 fragments in an activity when the a tablet is held in portrait. However I only have 2 of these fragments when in landscape. The problem I am having is when going from portrait to landscape the activity is creating the 3rd fragment. I receive and error as this fragment cannot be created.

I have worked out that this fragment is being created because it is in the back stack.

I have tried to remove the fragment in the onDestroy method by using

```
FragmentTransaction f = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
f.remove(mf);
f.commit();
```

However the I get an error saying that I cannot use this function after the onSaveInstanceState

What would be the correct way of taking this fragment out of the back stack?

### Update

I should probably add that the fragment I am having problems with is a mapFragment from this libary

https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps

The way I use it is like so

```
mf = MapFragment.newInstance(1, true);

ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.mapContainer, mf);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.addToBackStack("map");
ft.commit();
```

Comment: You just need to remove ` ft.addToBackStack("map") ` this line.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You add to the back state from the `FragmentTransaction` and remove from the backstack using `FragmentManager` pop methods:

```
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
trans.remove(myFrag);
trans.commit();
manager.popBackStack();
```

Comment: What happens if the fragment that you want to remove is not on top of the stack?

Comment: yeah, i tired not working when fragment is not top of the stack..
Still trying to figure that!

Comment: Did you find a solution to that problem ?

Comment: If you know beforehand that the fragment should not be part of the backstack, you might leave the "addToBackstrack(null)" out.

Comment: seems works http://i.imgur.com/nbHCM9P.png , but not clear fully why not ? I get a minium increment :(

Comment: i wonder why i had to call manager.popBackStack() after doing the remove. i would have though just the remove transaction would have gotten rid of it, thanks

Comment: I have 3 fragments. I want to remove only two fragments and replace another fragment in the same container. When I do fragmentManager.popBackStack(), previous(remaining one) fragment flashes for 1 second and then another fragment loaded. Is there any way to hide this transaction from the user?

Answer (score 25):

I created a code to jump to the desired back stack index, it worked fine to my purpose.

ie. I have Fragment1, Fragment2 and Fragment3, I want to jump from Fragment3 to Fragment1

I created a method called onBackPressed in Fragment3 that jumps to Fragment1

**Fragment3:**

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.popBackStack(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()-2).getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
}
```

In the activity, I need to know if my current fragment is the Fragment3, so I call the onBackPressed of my fragment instead calling super

**FragmentActivity:**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment_container);
    if (f instanceof Fragment3)
    {
        ((Fragment3)f).onBackPressed();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: But the code would turn messy in case of a large number of fragments, right? (I have 20 fragments)

Comment: @Kathir
`val backPressController = currentFragment as? BackPressController` 
            `?: return handleBackPress()`
        
        `val shouldPerformBackPress = backPressController.onBackPressed()`
        `if (shouldPerformBackPress) handleBackPress()`

Answer (score 2):

you show fragment in a container (with id= fragmentcontainer) so you remove fragment with:

```
 Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
            fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This transaction is already being added to the back stack

Answer (score 0):

In case you ended up here trying to figure out how to remove fragment(s) from backstack and you are using Android Jetpack Navigation component you could just use app:popUpTo and app:popUpToInclusive in action node of navigation graph xml to specify fragments that you want to pop out of back stack.
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop
Check this too
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51974492/4594986

Answer (score -13):

> What happens if the fragment that you want to remove is not on top of the stack?

Then you can use theses functions

`popBackStack(int arg0, int arg1);`

`popBackStack(String arg0, int arg1);`

Comment: I think this is wrong, if you read the documentation "... all states `up to that state` will be popped" so it doesn't remove exactly that fragment, it will remove everything on top of it in the stack (and the fragment itself depending of flag).

Comment: I don't see why people are downvoting Dornathal's answer and upvoting  @lxx 's comment! That's how stacks work [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type))!

Comment: @iSWORD Because the question also implies how you can remove only one fragment which is not on top