# remove the state of fragment from viewpager fragment activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to remove the state of `fragment` from a `viewpager` `fragmentActivity` where i am adding the fragments in to the `viewpager` .i am overriding `onBackPressed` in `fragment` activity in i want to remove the state of `fragment`.

Comment: yes it should finish() the fragment when i will press the back button.i mean remove the particular fragment from back stack

Answer (score 0):

You could reference the following article that quickly describes how to work with a backstack that you are speaking of within a fragment.

[Removing a fragment from backstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033019/removing-a-fragment-from-a-the-back-stack)

This kind of component could be achieved through overriding the `onBackPressed()` functionality within an Android Activity.