# Fragment is not removed from BackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I use BackStack to store fragments and it works fine. However when I want to remove a fragment from BackStack, nothing happens. 
I checked some questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033019/removing-a-fragment-from-the-back-stack) and saw that they do remove an item from BackStack by using popBackStack, like me, but it does not work for me.

This is my code:

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    String currentTag = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
    Fragment currentInstance = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentTag);
    fragmentTransaction.remove(currentInstance);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    fragmentManager.popBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    int count1 = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
```

currentInstance shows the topmost fragment correctly. Interestingly count and count1 are equals and the topmost item in stack remains after using popBackStack command. So I cant remove the topmost fragment from stack.

If use this code:

```
        String previousTag = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
        Fragment previousInstance = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(previousTag);

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, previousInstance,previousTag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I could replace fragment with previous one, but it's not correct way to do that, because I can't back for more than one fragment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it out: popBackStack method does not pop immediately after call. So in I have to use popBackStackImmediate method instead of popBackStack.
This is my final corrected code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()> 0) {
   fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

   String previousTag = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
   Fragment previousInstance = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(previousTag);

  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, previousInstance, previousTag);
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```