# How to skip specific fragment from backstack in onBackPress method?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have four main fragments and one minor fragment in my app.
Let's say Fragment A, B, C, D. 
There's a ListView at Fragment A. If user click list item, another Fragment (sub A) will be shown up. 
So.., if user click **A -> B -> C -> D**. 
The backstack will be **D -> C-> B-> A**. This is simple and easy. 
Here is my problem.., when user clicked a list item at Fragment A, The transition will be **A -> *sub A* -> B -> C -> D**. But I don't want **sub A** on backstack. My desired result is **D -> C -> B -> A**. I'm currently trying to skip the **sub A** but still couldn't find a suitable answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear back stack using fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186433/clear-back-stack-using-fragments)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing a Fragment from the back stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033019/removing-a-fragment-from-the-back-stack)

Answer (score 2):

Use this by overriding or any specific back button Click

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.popBackStack();
```

Override back button like this

```
// 2.0 and above
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}

// Before 2.0
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a boolean flag in your hosting activity to track whether Fragment sub A should be skipped:

private boolean skipFragment = false;

2. When navigating from Fragment sub A to any other fragment, set the skipFragment flag to true:

skipFragment = true;

3. In the hosting activity, override the onBackPressed() method to handle the back button press:

   ```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Check if Fragment should be skipped
    if (skipFragment) {
        // Clear the back stack up to Fragment A
        fragmentManager.popBackStack("FragmentATag", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        skipFragment = false; // Reset the flag
        return;
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
   }
   ```

Make sure you replace "FragmentATag" with the actual tag or name used for Fragment A when it was added to the back stack.

```
Fragment selectedFragment = new FragmentA();
    MainActivity.skipFragment = true;
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment)
            .addToBackStack("FragmentATag")
            .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below code is working for you.

```
FragmentManager fManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fManager.beginTransaction();
trans.remove(myFrag);//fragment you want to remove 
trans.commit();
fManager.popBackStack();
```

**Suggestion**

You should use Navigation component. It's very easy and more readable. If you use Navigation Component you can easily handle this type of case, while also helping you visualize your app’s navigation flow.

Try [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/get-started)