# Remove of the ChildFragmentManager is not working as expected

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have a Parent `Fragment` containing a Child `Fragment` which displays some data.

At some point the Child Fragment broadcasts that the user is finished (that there is no data to be displayed). At this point I want to remove this useless fragment but I somehow don't success. Am I missing something?

The way I **add** the fragment to the container (and it works really good):

```
if (swipeFragment == null)
    swipeFragment = new SwipeViewFragment();
if (getActivity() != null) {
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.jobSearchContainer, swipeFragment, "swipe").commitAllowingStateLoss();
    status = SWIPE;
}
```

The way I planed to **remove** it (but **it doesn't work** and it is all the variations I tried):

```
Fragment swipe = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("swipe");
if (swipe == null){
    throw new RuntimeException("Nope");
}
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(swipe).commit();
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(swipe).commit();
getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(swipe).commit();
```

I am missing something?

Thanks

PS: When I say that it doesn't work: I mean the fragment is not getting removed and I have no output in logcat

**UPDATE**

```
    Fragment swipe = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("swipe");
    if (swipe == null){
        throw new RuntimeException("Nope");
    }
    Log.d("DEBUG", ""+getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().size());
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(swipe).commit();
    getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    Log.d("DEBUG", ""+getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().size());
```

Has for a result:

```
1
1
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you get your Runtime Exception? Or is the fragment not removed..? Do you have any information in your logcat?

Comment: @Amy sorry, the fragment is not removed and I have no information/crash in my logcat. Silently fails...

Comment: You don't add your fragmentTransaction to the backstack, so I don't think popping it will bring any result. Have you tried to debug it? Set a breakpoint on the `swipe` fragment and check if it is shown, hidden, twice inflated or something like that.

Comment: @Amy thanks for your help, I found what it was and you couldn't find with only the information I gave, sorry... But the answer is pretty interesting ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged it and I finally found what it was all about and I'm sorry it is not related to the code I posted. Nevertheless, it is very interesting!

The problem was in the `onCreateView` of the view:

It used to be like this:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container);
// Bla bla
return null;
```

**THIS IS A PROBLEM** because I think the fragment is then somehow not associated with the view... But it works perfectly because the view uses the container and everything is fine

Instead, use:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
// Bla bla
return v;
```

If you do so, everything is fine!

I detected the problem because I tried to make the view transparent and I called the `Fragment.getView()` which returned me null.

That was a nasty one. Thx for your help guys!

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
Fragment swipe = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("swipe");
if (swipe == null){
    throw new RuntimeException("Nope");
}

getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(swipe).commit();
getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13074955/4628611)

Comment: Nope, if you look at the code I had; I have already that...

I have more informations, I edited my code