# How to remove only particular fragment from back stack?

Tags: android, fragment, back-stack, fragment-backstack

I am working with fragment architecture i designed login page in a fragment, i want to remove the only login fragment from back stack after user login successful and open another fragment, please help me.

Comment: wat have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033019/removing-a-fragment-from-the-back-stack

Comment: @Adrian,  What happens if the fragment that you want to remove is not on top of the stack?, actually i want to remove from back stack from other fragment

Comment: @Sihvam, i tried with below code
if (((HomeActivity)getActivity()).isFragmentInBackStack(Constants.LOGIN)){
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(Constants.LOGIN,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }

Comment: Actually i want to remove login fragment from back stack just after successfull login and show dashboard fragment again if we press back then login fragment should not appear.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this,**

You can add a tag to each fragment while adding them to the backstack and then pop fragment from backstack till the fragment with the tag you want is not reached.

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    for (int i = fm.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (!fm.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(tagname)) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }
        else
        {
         break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**replace()**

use replace(), it will replace the login fragment from the back stack before adding the new fragment you want to show

**example**

```
 Fragment fr1= new GoFragment();
 FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 ft.replace(R.id.FragmentContainer,newFragment);
  ft.addToBackStack(null);
  ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

> When the user Successfully login, do not add the Login Fragment to
>   BackStack, Then you need to Comment below the line.

```
ft.addToBackStack(null);
```

This Line adds your Fragment to BackStack when the user navigates from one fragment to another.

> Please refer the following link

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Performing Fragment Transactions Topic

Comment: Follow this Link, this may help http://www.andreabaccega.com/blog/2015/08/16/how-to-avoid-fragments-overlapping-due-to-backstack-nightmare-in-android/