# Do I need to remove a fragment if I pop it from the back stack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, fragment-backstack

I have looked at the solution below, and it looks strange to me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13074955/499206

Is it really necessary to explicitly remove the fragment using a fragment transaction if I pop it from the backstack using `PopBackStackImmediate()`?

Shouldn't the framework handle it for me?

At least I don't see the fragment in the fragment manager anymore after `PopBackStackImmediate()`.