# How to remove first entry in backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I want to remove first (oldest) entry from backstack when back stack entry count more than 3. I've tried something like this

```
fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(() -> {
            int backStackEntryCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
            if (backStackEntryCount > 3) {
                int firstEntryId = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(0).getId();
                fragmentManager.popBackStack(firstEntryId, 0);
            }
        });
```

But it doesn't work as I've expected

Comment: Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34794274/8063735

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove oldest fragment from fragment backstack. There are to two possible solution though: Either every time when you need to remove the oldest fragment from backstack, pop all fragments and push the only needed fragments. Or you may choose to use a custom backstack. You will find tutorials online for custom backstack implementation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

fragmentManager.remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(firstEntryId)).commit()