# Remove specefic fragment from backstack that is not on top of backstack

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment-backstack

Short Version:

I have 5 fragments all added to a container by [replace](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20androidx.fragment.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) method(`A -> B -> C -> D -> E`), now I want to remove 3rdfragment from my backStack(C) and stay in the current page, how to do it?

The problem:

I have 3 fragments, `FragmentA`, `FragmentB`, and `FragmentC`, and user navigates from `A to B then C`.
In FragmentC when user performs an action (I call it `ActionX`) I need to remove `FragmentB` from my fragment manager `BackStack` (while user still is in FragmentC) and I don't want user to notice anything, just when he presses back on phone different fragment shows (so if ActionX happened when user pressed back fragmentA shows, if not FragmentB shows)

This is how I show my `fragments` (I set fragment name for name and tag to find them when I need)

```
public void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        String tag = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

I tried solutions mentiond in some SO threads (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033019/removing-a-fragment-from-the-back-stack)) but they only work on top fragment in stack or they suggest to not FragmentB (which I cant because I don't know what will user do), also finding and removing FragmentB from stack does not work.
One solution is to override my Activity's onBackPressed and check if ActionX happend and pop my backStack twice.

what I tried:

1. this don't work (fragmentBInStack is not null but when I remove it nothing happens)

```
val fragmentBInStack = manager.findFragmentByTag(FragmentB::class.java.simpleName)
fragmentBInStack?.let {
    manager.beginTransaction().remove(it).commit()
}
```

2. this code removes both FragmentC and FragmentB and shows FragmentA (I want to stay in FragmentC) if I user 0 instad of `POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE` it only pops FragmentC and shows `FragmentB`

```
manager.popBackStack(FragmentB::class.java.simpleName, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
```

this is some sample code of what I want to do

```
class FragmentC : Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        view.findViewById<View>(R.id.action_x).setOnClickListener {

            //here I want to remove FragmentB from back Stack and stay in FragmentC, just later when user presses back I want to show FragmentA
            val manager = activity!!.supportFragmentManager
            val fragmentBInStack = manager.findFragmentByTag(FragmentB::class.java.simpleName)
            fragmentBInStack?.let {
                manager.beginTransaction().remove(it).commit()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, you have to add your fragments in seperate transaction, and change `replace` to `add`

```
supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2, tag2)
    .addToBackStack(tag2)
    .commit()
```

Then you remove fragment as you do:

```
val fragment2 = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag2)!!
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment2).commit()
```

The last step is just to popBackStack:

```
supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I always have problems with add when I use it so I prefer using replace, your code works well if I use add(). do you have any suggestions for removing fragment when I used replace()?

Comment: also when I use this code (using add) when I go back to FragmentA, I have to press back button twice to go back to the previous fragment (try it)

Comment: you can avoid pressing back button twice adding the first fragment without adding it to back stack

Comment: I understand, but replace method is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments. That's why it doesnt work

Comment: do you really yourself use add() in large applications?

Comment: Yes, I don't have problems with add()

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following approach: use the same instance of `ViewModel` (use `ViewModelProvider` of activity to create view model instance) with ActionX event `LiveData` in `FragmentB` and `FragmentC`. In `FragmentC` the value of `LiveData` is set, while `FragmentB` observes live data changes.

Here is the source code.

**1. view model**

```
class InterFragmentViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val actionXLiveData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
}
```

**2. FragmentC**

```
class FragmentC : AppCompatDialogFragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        view.findViewById<View>(R.id.action_x).setOnClickListener {
            ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(InterFragmentViewModel::class.java)
                .actionXLiveData.value = true
        }
    }
}
```

**3. FragmentB**

```
class FragmentB : AppCompatDialogFragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(InterFragmentViewModel::class.java)
            .actionXLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            parentFragmentManager.popBackStack()
        })

    }
}
```